# Why am I not getting emails for my questions subscriptions any more?

Tags: support, status-completed, email, tag-watching, subscriptions

Suddenly I don't get any emails regarding questions for the tags and topics I'm subscribed to.

I did check my profile and subscriptions under: [https://...?tab=subscription](https://stackexchange.com/users/6915932/k-amin?tab=subscriptions), and I see that everything looks fine.

I'm used to get each day couple of emails regarding the questions and tags I'm subscribed to.

I also did check the spam folder, but nothing there from Stack Overflow.

Any idea please what could be the reason?

Comment: I removed my subscription and tried to resubscribe, but I couldn't find the subscribe option anymore.

Comment: there is no more questions maybe ....

Comment: @Temani: No, everything is fine and there are 1000 of new questions there. It's really a strange behavior!

Comment: On MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313237

Comment: @Pang: Ok. Sorry, but what you want to say exactly with the link? It's the same issue, but there is no answer.

Comment: Same for me. No notification in last few days. I've even tried to re-subscribe. While I get *"Confirm your filter subscription"* email and I confirmed it, I receive no more notification after that.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: I even don't get the e-mail to confirm the subscription or changes I did, because I changed it from every day to every 3 hours!

Comment: You do not get any confirmation email, when you change frequency only. You get confirmation email only for new subscriptions.

Comment: @k.vincent I think he's saying (with the link) that it seems to be a network-wide issue

Comment: One of my low-volume tags has not sent me a message even though a new question arrived (so I confirm the observation in the question).  I've not changed anything at my end — what changed at the SO end, and is this a permanent loss of service or will it be fixed shortly?

Comment: I'm sure it's just yet another case of "*Meh, let's push to prod, they'll let us know if something breaks anyway*".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We moved to a new scheduler for the rest of the SE network this week (after gradually rolling out smaller sites) but stackexchange.com is treated slightly differently to the other sites on the network; it's not really part of the network and I made a bad assumption that it came back from an API call without later verifying that was the case.

We literally have 4 scheduled routes (out of 100s across the network) running on stackexchange.com so I'm afraid it got missed; there have been a few fires to put out this week and I'd forgotten by the time I came back to it towards the end of the week.

It stopped working on 24th July 13:00 UTC and I've just deployed and verified the fix for it now. Thanks for the report and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I got a notification, that covered the one question that I mentioned in a previous comment (to the main question), and a new one from today.  AFAICS, it is back in operation.  Thanks!

Comment: It‘s back to normal now. Got emails based on all my subscriptions for the different Tags and SOF questions. Great Job guys!

Comment: In stackoverflow.com, when I hover over a tag, I don't see "Subscribe" anymore, but only "Watch tag" and "Ignore tag".
How do you subscribe to notifications?

Comment: @NicolaBen You can use https://stackexchange.com/filters/  as a workaround - this is mentioned in comments to ['Favorite Tags' is now 'Tag Watching'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180#312247) and [How to subscribe to tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315135)

Comment: I didn't get any SO tag notification since 9th February 2019 + as Nicola Ben wrote there is no more "Subscribe" button on tag. I see nowhere that this feature has been deprecated and this is quite annoying!